# Android - Where is the error for missing AndroidManifest declarations?

Tags: android, service, android-manifest

I have some service, and the only way it will work is if it's defined in AndroidManifest.xml. However, if I do not register it, then I would expect an error somewhere in the logs to show up. Is this true, and if so, where is the error? If not, is it reasonable that no error is being logged?

Comment: give manifest and class code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be making a log. I think it says something along the lines of

> Could not find .YourServiceName have you declared this item in your
>   manifest?

There should be something like that in your log at the time you call `startService();`

Comment: So I've found the following coming from ActivityMananger:

`Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.hacking/.HelloIntentService } U=0: not found`


It was hard to find though, because there's so much logging going on all the time. I guess there's no way to filter between "obvious" and "non-obvious" logging?

Example of something not as useful:
`GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 5% free 9566K/9984K, paused 6ms+5ms, total 41ms`

Comment: Yeah it gets a bit tough to weed through the junk sometimes. Some devices/OS builds are better than others about keeping the logs fairly clean, but the ones that are bad are really bad. There is a Filter in Eclipse that lets you filter by Logtag, which is helpful for finding your own log messages. But is less useful for finding something like that which is coming from the system rather than your own app. Perhaps it does still have a log tag on it, if you make note of the tag used you could set up a filter that would pick up messages like this one.

Comment: yeah; the tag is ActivityManager but that doesn't fundamentally solve the noise problem. Thanks though